# Not able to print the list, how to rectify the errors?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

This program is to find the normalization of a vector but I am not able to print the list:

Def function:

```
def _unit_vector_sample_(vector):
    # calculate the magnitude
    x = vector[0]
    y = vector[1]
    z = vector[2]
    mag = ((x**2) + (y**2) + (z**2))**(1/2)
    # normalize the vector by dividing each component with the magnitude
    new_x = x/mag
    new_y = y/mag
    new_z = z/mag
    unit_vector = [new_x, new_y, new_z]
    #return unit_vector
```

Main program:

```
    vector=[2,3,-4]

    def _unit_vector_sample_(vector):
        print(unit_vector)
```

How can I rectify the errors?

Comment: Fix your question to actually be a question and format your code properly for display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def _unit_vector_sample_(vector):
    # calculate the magnitude
    x = vector[0]
    y = vector[1]
    z = vector[2]
    mag = ((x**2) + (y**2) + (z**2))**(1/2)
    # normalize the vector by dividing each component with the magnitude
    new_x = x/mag
    new_y = y/mag
    new_z = z/mag
    unit_vector = [new_x, new_y, new_z]
    return unit_vector

vector=[2,3,-4]  
print(_unit_vector_sample_(vector))
```

prints this output:

```
[0.3713906763541037, 0.5570860145311556, -0.7427813527082074]
```

You need to declare a return statement  in `your _unit_vector_sample` function. Otherwise your function will run but it cannot give it results back to main.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
def _unit_vector_sample_(vector):
    # calculate the magnitude
    x = vector[0]
    y = vector[1]
    z = vector[2]
    mag = ((x**2) + (y**2) + (z**2))**(1/2)
    # normalize the vector by dividing each component with the magnitude
    new_x = x/mag
    new_y = y/mag
    new_z = z/mag
    unit_vector = [new_x, new_y, new_z]
    print(unit_vector)

vector=[2,3,-4]
_unit_vector_sample_(vector)
```

resulting in the same output being printed:

```
[0.3713906763541037, 0.5570860145311556, -0.7427813527082074]
```

Here by calling print in your function the unit_vector gets printed every time the function is run.

Which one to use depends on what you want to do. 
Do you also want to assign the outcome of the fuction to a variable in main then use the first solution (and instead of directly printing the outcome of the function assign it to a variable). If this is not required you can use the second option.